# Is it possible to access the url of an external website in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, fetch, window

I need to access the parameters of an outside website's url, here's what I've tried so far:

```
fetch('https://someotherwebsite.com?code=aLongString');
    .then(getParams => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const code = params.get('code')
        console.log(code)
    }
)
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone please help?

**Edit:**
I failed to mention that the url I am trying to fetch includes a redirect_uri parameter. Which means when I actually hit that url I get taken to a different page with a different url, and it is the second url I am trying to access.

Url I want to fetch:

```
`https://someotherwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://differentwebsite.com`
```

Returns Url I want to access:

```
`https://differentwebsite.com?code=aLongString`
```

Currently my `code` variable is just returning undefined

Comment: Which is the result of `console.log(code)`?

Comment: [But it isn't working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: `window.location` is the URL of **your page**. If you want the URL in the string two lines earlier then just use the string from two lines earlier.

Comment: var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
console.log(c);

Comment: Thanks for the help so far guys, I have edited my question since I left out a rather important piece